# PHP Ajax Laravel Cause of the issue is clear, but the solution?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a Ajax code in the view. It sends the selected index (from a Select Box) to the Controller. The Controller forwards it to the Model and gets the correct result back. I can see in Firebug the Controller has the right value in its array when I do the print_r, so it would just take to send it back to the View for printing. But it fails there with "variable undefined". I can bypass that problem doing something like

if(empty($variable)){

then dont print else print it, 
if I do that, it does get to the Success part of the Ajax code, but I want it on the View html page. How do I finish this last part in a successful way? Here is the full code clearly:

VIEW:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#target").change(function() {
                    // alert($('#target option:selected').val());
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '<?php echo route("showhospitals");?>',
                        data: {'dataString': $('#target option:selected').val()},
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                           // alert(data);// CAN I USE THIS SUCCESS STUFF TO WRITE 
                           // TO THE HTML BLADE VIE PAGE INSTEAD OF ON AN ALERT?
                        }
                    });

                });


            });
</script>
```

THE CONTROLLER

```
public function postespecialidades(){
      if (Request::ajax())
{
   /*WE GET THE DATA FROM THE SELECT LIST VIA AJAX*/
    $data['input'] = Input::get('dataString');
    $dato = $data['input'];
    echo "the index number I got is: . $dato";
    /*WE SEND THAT DATA TO THE MODEL*/
    $hospital['input'] = with(new treatment)->sendData($dato);
    print_r($hospital['input']); //I CAN SEE THE CORRECT RESULT IN FIREBUG RESPONSE BUT CANT PASS IT TO THE VIEW
    return View::make('especialidades.especialidades')->with('hospital', $hospital);
    return $hospital['input'];
}

         else{
          echo "THE JQUERY IS NOT GETTING TO TALK TO ME";
        }
     }
  }
```

So, I would like the result printed on the View page, not on the alert window.

**Person info will be listed here.**

CAUSE OF THE ISSUE:

When the page loads, before having selected anything, the page crashes because it attempts to print a variable that has not had the chance of getting the value from the controller. That is where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

use one of this.

solution 1

double quote your php route

```
< script > $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#target").change(function() {
        // alert($('#target option:selected').val());
        formData = {
            dataString: $('#target option:selected').val();
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo route("showhospitals");?>",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                // alert(data);// CAN I USE THIS SUCCESS STUFF TO WRITE 
                // TO THE HTML BLADE VIE PAGE INSTEAD OF ON AN ALERT?
            }
        });
    });
}); < /script>
```

solution 2

use URL instead PHP route

```
< script > $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#target").change(function() {
        // alert($('#target option:selected').val());
        formData = {
            dataString: $('#target option:selected').val();
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/showhospitals',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                // alert(data);// CAN I USE THIS SUCCESS STUFF TO WRITE 
                // TO THE HTML BLADE VIE PAGE INSTEAD OF ON AN ALERT?
            }
        });
    });
}); < /script>
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammad, sukra. I will try the solution when I get home, as now I am not at my computer, I will tell you tomorrow, but I think the issue is that the $variable that I want to print in the View gets read when the page loads and because the controller has not passed yet the value (as I have not had the chance to select anything) then it is undefined and the page crashes upon loading. It is important to note that.

Comment: Hello Mohammad. I tried that without no change. I have the web online so you can try it yourself. I can give you the URL on a private chat

Comment: I am beginning to think I must be one of the best programmers of the world, because I always ask questions that almost nobody can answer.